# Give swipe gesture priority over button

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have two UIButtons in a view (one is YES, the other NO).  I now want to add a "did not answer", which would be indicated by a downward swipe on the view.

The problem is that the user may swipe down on the view, but in the process hit one of the buttons.  When this happens I want to ignore the button press if there was a swipe underway.  If it is just a tap on a button, the answer is recorded.

So, if the swipe occurs, I want to call the swipe gesture's action method.  If it is determined no swipe occurred but one of the two buttons was touched I want to call their respective action methods.  But if a button was touched in the process of a swipe, I want to call only the swipe gesture's action method.

I know there is a way but I'm wondering whether there is an EASY way of doing this.  TIA for suggestions.

Comment: Are you using a UISwipeGestureRecognizer or UIPanGestureRecognizer? (Asking since there's a super easy way of doing this if you're using a UIPanGestureRecognizer... If it's a UISwipeGestureRecognizer it's a bit more complicated since it's a discrete gesture.)

Comment: Actually, I have a different suggestion... One sec...

Comment: I'm flexible.  I could change to a pan easily, if that makes the other code more straightforward.

Comment: Actually, I just wrote an answer saying to use `cancelsTouchesInView`, but yeah, I think you need to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in order for that (or my other suggestion) to work since `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is a discrete gesture.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that's right actually re:`cancelTouchesInView`, but you can definitely either disable and re-enable the buttons at the start and end of a UIPanGestureRecognizer or set the buttons' gesture recognizers to fail when a pan is in progress.

Comment: I've re-added my cancelsTouchesInView answer though so you can give it a try. (I desperately need a nap, so I'll check back in later.)

Answer (score 3):

Since `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is a "discrete" gesture, it just triggers a single action when recognized and it won't allow you to detect the end of the gesture.

So to prevent other touches during the gesture, I'd recommend using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead since it can track your gesture from beginning to end. Then you can try setting your gesture's `cancelsTouchesInView` property to YES to cancel all other touches in the view that happen while that pan gesture is recognized, ex:

```
gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your buttons should be registering touch up in view, so that someone who taps on the button can drag off if they decide not to proceed.

For your other swipe gesture, your buttons will not register a touch up in view during a swipe gesture, even if the swipe passes over the button or ends on it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this seems to work.  On the gesture recognizer, I used:

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeDown:)];
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    swipeDown.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
    swipeDown.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
```

They delaysTouchesBegan = YES allows it to determine whether the swipe has occurred before passing the touches on to the buttons.  So, if you swipe, it calls the swipe GR, and if you touch either button, you get that.  Thanks for your answers...